# Unable to change values in JSON array via str_replace

Tags: php, json

I would like to change values in an array. Here is my starting array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => aaa         
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => bbb            
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => ccc
        )
)
```

I declare a searchterm (eg. "aaa") and a new name for it (eg. "test"). And than I do a `str_replace` to actually change it. 
Unfortunately nothing changes nor do I get an error message. Can you please help and tell me where my error is please?

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($json) ; $i++) { 
    $search  = $old_name;
    $replace = $new_name;
    str_replace($search, $replace, $json[$i]['name']); 
    print_r($json);     
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) says, this function doesn't update the array

> This function returns a string or an array with the replaced values.

you need to update it with the returned value:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($json) ; $i++) { 
    $search  = $old_name;
    $replace = $new_name;
    $json[$i]['name'] = str_replace($search, $replace, $json[$i]['name']);
    print_r($json);     
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`str_replace` returns a string. I think you are trying to use it as though it alters a parameter that was passed by reference. Instead you should assign the returned value to the array at the correct index.

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($json) ; $i++) { 
    $search  = $old_name;
    $replace = $new_name;
   $json[$i]['name'] = str_replace($search, $replace, $json[$i]['name']); 
    print_r($json);     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace/change more than one name, I suggest you to use the below code.

```
// define an array with keys as new name and value as old name ( name to be replaced).
$change_name_array= array('test'=>'aaa','another_test'=>'bbb');
// loop the array  
for ($i=0; $i < count($json) ; $i++) { 
    // check if the name is in defined array
    if(in_array($json[$i]['name'],$change_name_array)){
        // get the key and replace it. 
        $json[$i]['name'] = array_search($json[$i]['name'], $change_name_array);
    }
}
```

Out put: here aaa id replaced with test and bbb is replaced with another_test

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => test
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => another_test
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => ccc
        )

)
```